# Throw different errors in Promise chain?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a method in a WebApp server using Node that will perform several async actions, for example:

```
function saveTopValuePages( pageSize, clientId  )
        setExistingCredentials(clientId)
        .then(function() {
            return getViewIdByClientId(clientId);
        }, function(error) {
            throw new customErrors.SetExistingCredentials('test123')

        })
        .then(function(viewId) {
            return fetch(viewId, options)
        }, function(error) {
            throw new customErrors.GetViewIdByClientId('abcasdasd')
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response;
        })
```

After that  will my calling this functions from my routes:

```
 analytics.saveTopValuePages(pageSize, clientId)
    .then(function(data) {
        res.status(200)send({ message: 'success'})
        }

    }).catch(customErrors.SetExistingCredentials, function(error) {
        res.status(400).send({ error: error})
    }).catch(customErrors.GetViewIdByClientId, function(error) {
        res.status(401).send({error: error})
    }).catch(function(e){
    res.status(500).send({ error: "Unknown internal server error" });
});
```

As you can see in my example, I am trying to throw an error depending in which part of the process failed. This would work if all those actions were independently from each other, but the opposite is true. So, if `setExistingCredentials` fails, all the following functions will fail.

This is provoking that if `setExistingCredentials` fails, the error will be throw as well as the `GetViewIdByClientId` error. Finally, the error that I will be catching would be the last one (`GetViewIdByClientId` in this case), and not the correct one.

So, I am not sure if this would be a correct approach, of if there is any other promises pattern to achieve the results I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you dont use the native error ? `var error = new Error("An Error occurred"); throw error;`

Comment: I try that approach earlier, but it is the same, the last error is the one propagated to the catch, so it is always a "getViewIdByClientId" error.

Comment: How will subsequent operations run if the operations they depend on throw?

Comment: They shouldn't run, since if the credentials cannot be set (for example) the rest of the functions will not be able to fulfill.

Comment: As soon as a promise rejects in a promise chain, nothing else in the chain is executed.  So, the first rejection causes the chain to stop.  There is never more than one error unless you specifically "eat" an error and let the chain continue.  So. it's unclear to me what problem you're really trying to solve.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how "kosher" this is

```
function saveTopValuePages( pageSize, clientId  ) {
    setExistingCredentials(clientId)
    .then(function() {
        return getViewIdByClientId(clientId);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        throw { custom: customErrors, type: 'SetExistingCredentials', arg: 'test123' }

    })
    .then(function(viewId) {
        return fetch(viewId, options)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.custom == customErrors) {
            throw new customErrors[error.type](error.arg);
        }
        throw new customErrors.GetViewIdByClientId('abcasdasd')
    });
    // next 3 lines are actually redundant 
    //.then(function(response) {
    //    return response;
    //})
}
```

If that doesn't work, then you wont like it - I don't like it - but sometimes it has to be done - nesting!

```
function saveTopValuePages( pageSize, clientId  ) {
    setExistingCredentials(clientId)
    .then(function() {
        return getViewIdByClientId(clientId).then(function(viewId) {
            return fetch(viewId, options)
        }, function(error) {
            throw new customErrors.GetViewIdByClientId('abcasdasd')
        });
    }, function(error) {
        throw new customErrors.SetExistingCredentials('test123')
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response;
    })
}
```

Of course, you could mitigate this nastiness by creating a function

```
function getView(clientId) {
    return getViewIdByClientId(clientId).then(function(viewId) {
        return fetch(viewId, options)
    }, function(error) {
        throw new customErrors.GetViewIdByClientId('abcasdasd')
    });
}
function saveTopValuePages( pageSize, clientId  ) {
    setExistingCredentials(clientId)
    .then(function() {
        return getView(clientId);
    }, function(error) {
        throw new customErrors.SetExistingCredentials('test123')
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response;
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was pondering nesting as as possible solution, but I have started to work with promises recently and I was wondering if there wasn't a more elegant solution/pattern to handle this kind of cases. Thanks!